# How can I split a string on a carriage return with sscanf? 

Tags: c

How can I split a string on a carriage return (`\r\n` or just `\n`) with `sscanf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying Chris's answer slightly, to determine when the second part begins:

```
const char *str = ... // = source string
while (str[0]) {
   char buffer[100];
   int n;
   sscanf(str, " %99[^\r\n]%n", buffer, &n); // note space, to skip white space
   str += n; // advance to next \n or \r, or to end (nul), or to 100th char
   // ... process buffer
}
```

Although I would prefer to use `strtok()` or `strpbrk()`.  For example:

```
char *str = ... // = source string--not constant, as it gets destroyed
char *out = strtok(str, "\r\n");
while (out) {
   // ... process 'out'
   out = strtok(0, "\r\n"); // advance to next part
}
```

Comment: can you show some sample of the usage of strok to carriage returns?

Comment: God bless you! I struggled with this for 2 hours! Which such a ridiculously arcane solution!

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` doesn't split strings, it parses them.  If you want to read up to (and not including) a carriage return or newline, you can use:

```
char buffer[100];
scanf("%99[^\r\n]", buffer);
```

though you're probably better off just using fgets and then stripping off the unwanted trailing characters.